# Magento 2.2.5 How to add the Datepicker in frontend(product view page)

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5

I'm using Magento 2.2.5. How to add the Datepicker in frontend(product view page).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by js.

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {

    $("#ElementId").calendar({
         buttonText: "<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>"
    });

    });
</script>
```